# Changing the .pem key for a running EC2-instance without stopping the running instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Please help me in changing the key pair for the running ec2-instance without stopping the instance.Please help me with this.

Regards,
Ashwini.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a Linux EC2 instance, and the example is for an Ubuntu AMI. In any case the instructions are very similar.

```
ssh ubuntu@ec2-host.compute-1.amazonaws.com
edit ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
# remove the entry in the above file.
# add your new public key
```

If you haven't added keys or users to the machine that's all you need to do. There should only be one entry in the `authorized_keys` file when you open it, and there should only be one when you've finished. I recommend logging in from another session to ensure you haven't broken anything. If so, you still have a session open.

Verify that your new key has the same format. It should be approximately the same length. If not, you'll need to convert it. [Here's a sample of key conversion, though it isn't precisely what you might need](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116303/convert-amazon-pem-key-to-putty-ppk-key-linux).